# What are some examples of research papers that are very generally viewed as "well-written"?

Tags: publications, writing, writing-style

What are some examples of research papers that are very generally viewed as "well-written"?

And by "generally" I refer to something which is not dependent so much on "subjective factors" of taste.

Comment: Please don't ask "shopping questions".

Comment: @Roland Is this such? I think this is a question about the perception of "well-written research paper".

Comment: Which field is of interest to OP?

Comment: @Aruralreader Any field, but intuitively such paper should not be "too easy", because easy topics are easy to write about.

Comment: The American Mathematical Society and the Mathematical Association of America give out some awards for papers and textbooks that are focused on the quality of exposition. Look at the winners, they will give some fine examples of what you’re looking for.